# XPath to find attributes where the name starts with a given value

Tags: xpath, attributes

With this xml:

```
<div val1="q">a</div>
<div val2="w">b</div>
<div val3="e">c</div>
<div some="r">d</div>
<div thing="t">f</div>
<div name="y">g</div>
```

we want to find only

```
<div val1="q">a</div>
<div val2="w">b</div>
<div val3="e">c</div>
```

which are those nodes having an attribute where the attribute **name** begins with `val`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this :

```
//div/@*[starts-with(name(.), 'val')]
```

if you know that you are looking for the first attribute of the div element.

**Edit:**

Sorry didn't realize you wanted to select the elements themselves. You could use parent::div or what you did, but the proper way of doing this would be to select directly the div themselves :

```
//div[@*[starts-with(name(), 'val')]]
```

Comment: I need to get div elements wich have specific attributes.
Not attributes and their values as is in 
`//div/@*[starts-with(name(.), 'val')]`

Comment: using **nokogiri** i got:

`"<div val1="q">a</div>".xpath("//div/@*[starts-with(name(.), 'val')]") #=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x80fea968 name="val1" value="q">]`

Comment: It works with `//div/@*[starts-with(name(.), 'val')]/..`

Great thx

Comment: @dom1nga: See my answer for a correct XPath expression that selects exactly the nodes you are after. :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with .../@val* ?

Comment: `//*[@val*]`has incorrect syntax

`//*['@val*']` return wrong search results, contains 'val' in values, but not in attributes

Answer (score 0):

> which are those nodes having an attribute where the attribute name
>   begins with `val`

**Use**:

```
//div[@*[starts-with(name(), 'val')]]
```

This selects any `div` element in the document, that has at least one attribute, whose name starts with the string `"val"`.

**XSLT - based verification**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@*[starts-with(name(), 'val')]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (produced from the provided XML fragment):

```
<html>
    <div val1="q">a</div>
    <div val2="w">b</div>
    <div val3="e">c</div>
    <div some="r">d</div>
    <div thing="t">f</div>
    <div name="y">g</div>
</html>
```

**selects and outputs the wanted nodes:**

```
<div val1="q">a</div>
<div val2="w">b</div>
<div val3="e">c</div>
```