# import.io : Inserting an Independent row into result using XPATH

Tags: xpath, import.io

I am trying to scrape this site using import.io: [ScoreCard](http://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/14770/sri-lanka-vs-pakistan-2nd-test-pakistan-tour-of-sri-lanka-2015)

I am able to get the batting scores successfully but I want to insert additional column in the end which can tell me about the innings. So it should be relative to the name of batsman.

I tried to use XPATH: `//*[@id="innings_1"]/div[1]/div/h4/b`
but that will always return First Inning as ID is `"innings_1"`.
Other IDs are `innings_2/3/4` etc. Is there any way in XPATH where I can get this element relative to Batsman column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I did in order to get the desired result:

I used following XPATH value.
.//a/ancestor::div/div[1]/div/h4/b

.//a was providing me name of Batsmen. I searched for its ancestors and the path div[1]/div/h4/b was being used by only Innings section.. So it did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [starts-with()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308328/xpath-to-find-attributes-where-the-name-starts-with-a-given-value):

`//*[starts-with(@id,'innings_')/div/div/h4/b`

Comment: Hi Brent, your solution starts showing both team names in same cell.. Like below:   Barbados Innings - 148/8 (20 overs)St Lucia Zouks Innings - 133/9 (20 overs)... I used this link: http://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/14731/st-lucia-zouks-vs-barbados-tridents-10th-match-caribbean-premier-league-2015.... I am looking for TeamName from which batsman is playing in that cell...